# Maven eclipse project using editable source code for the maven dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar

I'm somewhat new to maven and I have a situation where I want to be able to use a library/dependency in my project that I have the source code for so I can change the library around. Right now I have my main maven project and I have the code pulled down for the library I want to use. The source code for the library is in separate maven projects within my eclipse.

So In my Eclipse Package Explorer:
MyProject (maven project)
Library Part A (maven project)
Library Part B (maven project)
Library Part C (maven project)

I want to link my project to be able to use the modified versions on the library code. I might have to make a jar file out of each and link it that way but I am just not sure. I haven't found a good example online how to do this.

What I am really doing is working with a wicket quickstart maven project and want to use my own wicket framework source code instead of the jars supplied with the quickstart.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with the orginal jar then use it directly from a maven repository, for example the central repository. You can search your library here: http://search.maven.org/

If not you can install your jar into your local maven repository using mvn:install. If your work at a company where you have a company repository you will need to deploy it to your company repository, so others can use it.

Installing intoo local repository:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Deploying to remote repository:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html

Generally thats info you can find easily on Google, no need to ask so quickly at StackO.

Comment: I had been googling for a few hours and tried multiple tutorials and could not get it to work. I might have just been looking at the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

Its good that you've already downloaded the library source files, you can modify the groupId and artifactId of the library. Once that is done, you can add it as a dependency in your new project. building your version of the library will publish it to your local repository where it's accessible.

Comment: I'll give this a try when I have some time. Been busy with some other stuff and I'll let you know how it goes.